# How to graph 3D functions of two variables on Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

How to graph this on wolfram, google, or other free software:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
x(s, t) &= a\cos(mt) \cos^{k}(ns) &&\cos(t) &&\cos(s), \\
y(s, t) &= a\cos(mt) \cos^{k}(ns) &&\sin(t) &&\cos(s), \\
z(s, t) &= a\cos(mt) \cos^{k}(ns) &&\sin(s) &&
\end{alignat*}

The following is: $m = 4$, $n = 1$, and $k = 8$:

[image: A three-dimensional rose with eight lobes]

The underlying idea is to take $\rho = \cos(m\theta)\cos^{k}(n\phi)$ in spherical coordinates
$$
(x, y, z) = (\rho\cos\theta \cos\phi, \rho\sin\theta \cos\phi, \rho\sin\phi).
$$

[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209858/what-equation-will-create-a-3d-rose-curve)

Edit: I tried modifying a parametricplot3D that was pre-existing:

[parametricplot3d[{(1+ cos(u/2)*sin(v)- sin(u/2)*sin(2*v))*cos(u), (1+ cos(u/2)*sin(v)- sin(u/2)*sin(2*v))*sin(u), sin(u/2)*sin(v)+ cos(u/2)*sin(2*v)}, {u,0,2*Pi},{v,0,2*Pi}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot3d[%7B%281%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29-%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%29*cos%28u%29,%20%281%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29-%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%29*sin%28u%29,%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D])
[image]

This works in wolfram: Bold = changed.
[parametricplot3d[{**cos(3*u)*cos(4*v)^2*cos(u)*cos(v)**, (1+ cos(u/2)*sin(v)- sin(u/2)*sin(2*v))*sin(u), sin(u/2)*sin(v)+ cos(u/2)*sin(2*v)}, {u,0,2*Pi},{v,0,2*Pi}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot3d[%7Bcos%283*u%29*cos%284*v%29%5E2*cos%28u%29*cos%28v%29,%20%281%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29-%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%29*sin%28u%29,%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D])

[image]

This Barely Does:
[parametricplot3d[{cos(3*u)*cos(4*v)^2*cos(u)*cos(v), cos(3*u)*cos(4*v)^2*cos(u)*cos(v), sin(u/2)*sin(v)+ cos(u/2)*sin(2*v)}, {u,0,2*Pi},{v,0,2*Pi}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot3d[%7Bcos%283*u%29*cos%284*v%29%5E2*cos%28u%29*cos%28v%29,%20cos%283*u%29*cos%284*v%29%5E2*cos%28u%29*cos%28v%29,%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D])

[image]

This Doesn't:
parametricplot3d[{**cos(3*u)*cos(4*v)^2*cos(u)*cos(v), (cos(3*u)*cos(4*v)^2*cos(u)*cos(v), (cos(3*u)*cos(4*v)^2*sin(v)**, {u,0,2*Pi},{v,0,2*Pi}]

Is the Problem Computation time?

Comment: The key word in Wolfram Alpha is "3D parametric plot". Here's an example I found online, you can adjust it to your function: `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot3d[%7B%281%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29-%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%29*cos%28u%29,%20%281%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29-%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%29*sin%28u%29,%20sin%28u%2F2%29*sin%28v%29%2B%20cos%28u%2F2%29*sin%282*v%29%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D])`

Comment: @Rahul I have attmepted that without success, Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at your "This Barely Does" and "This Doesn't", you have syntax problems. The second argument has unbalanced parentheses (an extra open parenthesis '(' appears). The third argument also has an unbalanced parenthesis. Furthermore, the third argument should close with closed brace '}'.

Comment: [This seems to work](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+parametric+plot+%5B+%7B+Cos(3*u)*(Cos(4*v)%5E2)*Cos(u)*Cos(v),+Cos(3*u)*(Cos(4*v)%5E2)*Sin(u)*Cos(v),+Cos(3*u)*(Cos(4*v)%5E2)*Sin(v)+%7D,+%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D%5D).

Comment: @WillieWong Wow that looks amazing! I seem to have forgotten how fickle parentheses can be.