# Higher dimensional roses.

Tags: geometry

We know that the $2n$ petal rose $$r=\sin n\theta$$ occupies half the area of the unit circle regardless of the number of petals while the arc-length grows without bound.

Are there such objects in higher dimensions?

Comment: Does Gabriel's Horn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn, work?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209858/what-equation-will-create-a-3d-rose-curve and http://www.grad.hr/sgorjanc/Links/roses.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this "rose" suffice in three dimensions?

[image]

Comment: Good for three dimensions